# Javascript circular dependency in GraphQL code

Tags: javascript, circular-dependency, graphql

I am new to Javascript and don't know how to solve this problem. I am creating a GraphQL service to provide query to a database, I would like to define three type: Person, Company and Relationship

```
type Relation: {
  person: Person
  company: Company
｝

type Person: {
  relationship: Relation
}

type Company: {
  relationship: Relation
}
```

As you can see, they are mutually depended, I will got Person and Company `undefined`, is there a way to resolve this?

database schema:

```
// -------------------- Object(company) --------------------
objectType = new GraphQLObjectType ({
  name: 'Object',
  description: 'Object could be a Company, FinancialOrg, Person or Product.',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    entity_type: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      description: 'could be Company, FinancialOrg, Person or Product.'
    },
    entity_id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
    },
    parent_id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    name: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    normalized_name: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    permalink: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    }
  },
  resolveType: function(object) {
    return dbHandler.findObjectById(object.id);
  }
})

// -------------------- Relationship --------------------
var relationshipType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Relationship',
  description: 'Describe the relationship between a person and a object(Corporation, fund)',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
    },
    relationship_id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
    },
    person_object_id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    relationship_object_id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      description: 'A Corporation or a Fund',
    },
  }
});

// -------------------- Person Type --------------------
personType = new GraphQLObjectType ({
  name: 'Person',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
    },
    object_id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    first_name: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    last_name: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    birthplace: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    affiliation_name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: It may be possible to model your types in a different way. Can you provide more details about how your database schema looks like?

Comment: Thank you @AhmadFerdousBinAlam I sort of figure out how to solve this, I actually leave all three types Relation, Person and Company 'unlinked', but created another layer with more complex version of the three within 'relations'.

Comment: I've had this problem in my own project. The answer is to use `Interfaces` for GraphQL. http://graphql.org/docs/api-reference-type-system/#graphqlinterfacetype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you wouldn't define a special Relationship type. In GraphQL, relationships among types are defined in the types themselves.

As examples, within your `personType`, you can have a field called `companies`, which resolves to a list of companies (`companyType`s) that person is part of. In your `companyType`, you could similarly define a field `people` that would resolve to a list of `personType`s.

This would give you essentially a many-to-many relationship between the two types, which it sounds like is defined in your database.

A `personType` in this style might look like:

```
personType = new GraphQLObjectType ({
  name: 'Person',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
    },
    companies: {
      type: new GraphQLList(companyType),
      resolve: person => dbHandler.getAssociatedCompanies(person.id),
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

As for circular dependency issues, notice above that rather than using an object literal for `fields`, you can instead use a function which returns the object, which will not cause any problems (though your linter might complain).

I would definitely suggest reading through the [GraphQL Types](http://graphql.org/docs/api-reference-type-system/) as well and making sure you've chosen appropriate types for your fields. Once you're comfortable enough you will definitely want to investigate `GraphQLInterfaceType`, which allows you to define common fields other types can implement. Ultimately it's probably a better route to define your types separately and have them implement an interface rather than having a generic `objectType`.

Also note that `resolveType` probably doesn't do what you think it does. From the GraphQL Types: "[resolveType is] a function to determine which type is actually used when the field is resolved." You see that on GraphQL types that can be composed of multiple types, like `GraphQLInterfaceType` and `GraphQLUnionType`.

The [Star Wars example](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/__tests__/starWarsSchema.js) helped me wrap my head around this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restructure your GraphQL endpoints to something like this

```
type Person: {
  employers: [Company],
  ...personAttributes
}

type Company: {
  employees: [Person],
  ...companyAttributes
}
```

In the database schema (I guess you're using a relational database) you'll need 3 tables:

- Persons
- Companies
- Relationships

[This article explains how to model many-to-many relationships like the one you have.](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx)

Note: If one person can only work at one company at a time, the schema is much simpler.